# How to store hashed pws into a db with Apache Shiro?

Tags: java, database, dao, shiro, jdbcrealm

I have been looking all over the place with no luck to what I am trying to do.

I am looking to hash and salt my user passwords and store them into the DB.  The issue is, how do I store them?

I have looked at this http://shiro.apache.org/realm.html#Realm-authentication which I have found similar answers, but it doesn't make sense.

```
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.Sha256Hash;
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.RandomNumberGenerator;
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.SecureRandomNumberGenerator;
...

//We'll use a Random Number Generator to generate salts.  This
//is much more secure than using a username as a salt or not
//having a salt at all.  Shiro makes this easy.
//
//Note that a normal app would reference an attribute rather
//than create a new RNG every time:
RandomNumberGenerator rng = new SecureRandomNumberGenerator();
Object salt = rng.nextBytes();

//Now hash the plain-text password with the random salt and multiple
//iterations and then Base64-encode the value (requires less space than Hex):
String hashedPasswordBase64 = new Sha256Hash(plainTextPassword, salt, 1024).toBase64();

User user = new User(username, hashedPasswordBase64);
//save the salt with the new account.  The HashedCredentialsMatcher
//will need it later when handling login attempts:
user.setPasswordSalt(salt);
userDAO.create(user);
```

User nor "UserDAO" exists currently from what I'm seeing, and all of these examples seem to use older Shiro examples.

When I look at the "PasswordService" javadoc I read

Account Creation or Password Reset

```
Whenever you create a new user account or reset that account's password,
```

we must translate the end-user submitted raw/plaintext password value to a
 string format that is much safer to store. You do that by calling the 
encryptPassword(Object) method to create the safer value. For example:

```
 String submittedPlaintextPassword = ...
 String encryptedValue = passwordService.encryptPassword(submittedPlaintextPassword);
 ...
 userAccount.setPassword(encryptedValue);
 userAccount.save(); //create or update to your data store

Be sure to save this encrypted password in your data store 
and never the original/raw submitted password.
```

but what is "userAccount?"

A lot of times the documentation is very vague.

However I did notice there is a "SubjectDAO" Class, but no UserDAO class...

So yeah I'm confused on what to do next, so if anyone could help me I would appreciate it greatly!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the Documentation is refering `User` and `UserDAO` as your own User Model Entity (Table) and User Data Access Layer Entity (Class to Save, Update, Delete and Retrieve). These necessarily not required to be a part of Apache Shiro (Reason some Data Access Layer may be in RDBMS, Some in In-memory dbs, some could even be in properties file, why not?)

You must implement `User` and `UserDAO` to save to your own persistence store.

`UserAccount` also is the Model object you use when you want to register user accounts. Like the Gmail signup.

You must know that Apache Shiro is just a layer for Security (Authentication, Authorization, etc). Persistence must be implemented by you.

Strongly advice you to check out Spring Data JPA and Spring Security.

Comment: I am not very familiar with persistence, so thank you for the info.

I figured shiro realms dealt with everything, not just reading from it...

I've heard that Spring takes a lot of learning, but I've spent a lot of time with Shiro.  I like it, but the documentation is lacking a lot.

I guess in a sense I can take the generated password and use an SQL query to add it to a DB, or should I use some sort of persistence API?  

It seems that persistence is something preferred these days, but I'm new to this so I don't know.

Why do you like spring more than shiro?

thanks

Comment: Yes you can use plain JDBC queries to implement Persistence layer, but using an API reduces the time. Spring eco system is easy learn works well together. Spring Security which is similar to Shiro is the most widely used API for Security.

Comment: Thanks, so I think I will use regular queries, but maybe it's better to learn JPA.  Any advice on Persistence layers?

You are probably one of the first people to say it's easy, even looking at shiro vs spring shows a lot of people talking about how difficult or "complex" it is, but I haven't looked at it myself.

I hear Spring is used all over the place, so I don't doubt it's big.

Shiro seemed easy and had a lot to offer, but it definitely took some time to get it set up (and still taking time).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

When you are hashing the password :

```
DefaultPasswordService passwordService = new DefaultPasswordService();
String encytptedPwd= passwordService.encryptPassword("your password");
```

Above api will generate password including salt.

Update this password using JDBC native api...

When you are implementing the JDBCRealm

```
PasswordMatcher credentialsMatcher = new PasswordMatcher();
this.setCredentialsMatcher(credentialsMatcher);
```

above will set the credential matcher and use `SimpleAuthenticationInfo` to validate your login.

The PasswordMatcher can be configured to use an ini file too.

Comment: Thanks for this.

Since I already have my ini file configured for my web app, I figured it would be best to keep that.

How would I access my ini file data?

Also according to something I found it says this

# privateSalt needs to be base64-encoded in shiro.ini but not in the Java code
#Salt is randomly generated with the Secure Generator
##saltGenerator = org.apache.shiro.crypto.SecureRandomNumberGenerator
##hashService.privateSalt = saltGenerator.nextBytes.toBase64

So with this how would I access lets say the field "saltGenerator?"

from within the ini?